# Rename a single file by replacing/removing some text

Tags: powershell, rename

I am trying to rename a single file by removing some text from its name. The following error happens to me:

```
PS> rni .\SomeFileName.todo.asc { $_ -replace ".todo" }

Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified
as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without
input.
```

I have also tried the following approach and it's also in error:

```
PS> SomeFileName.todo.asc | rni -newname { $_ -replace ".todo" }

SomeFileName.todo.asc : The term 'SomeFileName.todo.asc' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several lines:

```
$filename = ".\SomeFileName.todo.asc";
$newname = $filename -replace "\.todo", "";
rni $filename $newname;
```

You can also do this in one line:

```
gi SomeFileName.todo.asc | rni -newname { $_ -replace "\.todo" }
```

Both of these give the following result:

```
SomeFileName.asc
```

Comment: Thank you. I subsequently found and added a single line solution.

Comment: Nice find. I tried to find the one line solution too because I saw you could do it with a loop of a directory.

Comment: Remember that `-match` and `-replace` uses regex for the match patterns. You should escape the period so it won't mess ut files that might be called `SomeFileName-todo.asc` etc.  Like `$_ -replace '\.todo'`